# Android bindingadapter not updating value

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, android-databinding, android-mvvm

I am trying to use binding adapter to set image URL in "imageView" with help of Picasso.

My XML Image View:

```
  <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgProfile"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="110dp"
                        android:background="@color/transparent"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        bind:imgUrl="@{vm.imageUrl}"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:translationZ="5dp" />
```

My ViewModel:

```
  public ObservableField<String> getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

private ObservableField<String> imageUrl = new ObservableField<>();


@BindingAdapter({"bind:imgUrl"})
public static void setProfilePicture(ImageView imageView, String imgUrl) {
    if (imgUrl == null) {
        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.ic_registration_logo).into(imageView);
    } else
        Picasso.get().load(imgUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_registration_logo).into(imageView);
}
```

Now when in starting "setProfilePicture" called and default image is set. Then I make a API call to get URL of image on success of API I set value to "imageUrl"

```
  imageUrl.set("URL RECEIVED FROM SERVER");
```

It is not updating on view. Means "setProfilePicture" is not getting called again.

Comment: I debug the viewModel, so very first "setProfilePicture" is called but when I setImageUrl, "setProfilePicture" is not getting called again.

Comment: Yes I tried it, even I call imageUrl.set("new value"). In binding there is a method "onChangeVmImageUrl" is not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.imageUrl)` after changing value.

> What [notifyPropertyChanged(int fieldId)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BaseObservable#notifypropertychanged) does?
>
> Notifies listeners that a specific property has changed. The getter
>   for the property that changes should be marked with `Bindable` to
>   generate a field in **BR** to be used as fieldId.

Check more info from [**here**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability#observable_objects)

Comment: I am already using ObservableField, when I set value of ObservableField it automatically calls notifyChange

Answer (score 0):

> I am already using ObservableField, when I set value of
>   ObservableField it automatically calls notifyChange

Yes, you don't need to notify when you are using `ObservableField`.

I just checked this, and it is **working perfectly**. Because I can't see your all code, so I can't tell where the issue is.

I used `Handler.postDelayed()`, that will behave like api call.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<variable
    name="item"
    type="com.innovanathinklabs.sample.data.Image"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    bind:imgUrl="@{item.url}"/>
```

**Image.java**

```
public class Image {
    private ObservableField<String> url = new ObservableField<>();

    public ObservableField<String> getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(ObservableField<String> url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @BindingAdapter({"bind:imgUrl"})
    public static void setProfilePicture(ImageView imageView, String imgUrl) {
        Picasso.get().load(imgUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_sync).into(imageView);
    }
}
```

**ActivityMain.java**

```
ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
final String URL_1 = "https://sftextures.com/texture/2704/0/2703/wallpaper-pattern-primitives-shades-of-grey-smaller-details-abstract-huge-texture-256x256.jpg";
final String URL_2 = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Breathe-preferences-desktop-wallpaper.svg/128px-Breathe-preferences-desktop-wallpaper.svg.png";
Image item = new Image();
item.getUrl().set(URL_1);
binding.setItem(item);
new Handler().postDelayed(() -> binding.getItem().getUrl().set(URL_2), 4000);
```

**Suggestion**

Why to create many namespaces? Just use existing namespace.

```
@BindingAdapter({"android:src"})
```

and

```
android:src="@{item.url}"
```